# Survival analysis to model waiting times for buses

Tags: modeling, survival

I need some way to model what is the expected waiting times when someone can take one of a set of buses, with different time/frequency characteristics.

Bus 1 - There are 10 buses an hour, but regularity is very poor
In this case, we can easily use an exponential survival model, with `lambda=1/6` (one bus every 6 minutes). We will have a constant **hazard function** `1: h(t) = 1/6`. The average waiting time is `lambda`, i.e., **6 minutes**

Bus 2 - The same, with 8 buses an hour. `2: h(t) = 1/8`.

It's easy to model waiting times for a combination of bus 1 or 2 with `1+2: h(t) = 1/6 + 1/8`

Bus 3 - There are also 10 buses per hour, however there is holding control, and buses arrive in regular intervals. (i.e., the time between two consecutive buses has very low variation, and is always very close to 6 minutes). In this case, it is easy to know that, although frequency is the same as *bus 1*, the average waiting time is half, **3 minutes**.

I was wondering how to model bus 3 in terms of survival models, (i.e. what's its hazard function), in two situations:

- When the time until next bus is unknown, i.e., only the frequency is known, and,
- when time until next bus is known, i.e., we know the exact schedule for that bus, as well as the exact arrival time at stop.

I imagine bus 3 could be modelled as a **Weibull** distribution with very high *beta*

Also, is there a closed formula for the combined survival function or hazard function when someone can take either bus 1 or bus 3?